Unable to Load Conotrollers in gazebo ROS2
I am trying to simulate UR5 robotic arm. After running gazebo simulation launch file the controllers are not loaded and i am getting the following error in the terminal. I am  new to ROS2 hence i used the GPT to create the launch file. Thanks in advance.
terminal output when i try to launch it
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [9450]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [9452]
[INFO] [gzserver-3]: process started with pid [9454]
[INFO] [gzclient-4]: process started with pid [9456]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-5]: process started with pid [9458]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-6]: process started with pid [9460]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [9462]
[ros2_control_node-6] [INFO] [1725511190.773770863] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511190.773948344] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511190.774307493] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link1_1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511190.774348270] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link2_p1_1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511190.774362216] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link2_p2_1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511190.774373807] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link2_p3_1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511190.774386601] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link3_1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511190.774398253] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link4_1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511190.774409514] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link5_1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511190.774421456] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link6_1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511190.774432897] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[ros2_control_node-6] [INFO] [1725511190.777884655] [controller_manager]: update rate is 1000 Hz
[ros2_control_node-6] [INFO] [1725511190.782524257] [controller_manager]: Successful set up FIFO RT scheduling policy with priority 50.
[joint_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1725511191.458917573] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1725511191.613625347] [spawner_ur5_controllers]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1725511191.616004464] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1725511191.616993167] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-5] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-5]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1725511191.622510908] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1725511191.635145150] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1725511191.636070556] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1725511192.649579893] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-5] [INFO] [1725511193.007466519] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [ur5_assembly]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-5]: process has finished cleanly [pid 9458]
[spawner-7] [WARN] [1725511201.631335207] [spawner_ur5_controllers]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1725511201.632951972] [spawner_ur5_controllers]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[spawner-7] [WARN] [1725511211.651411025] [spawner_ur5_controllers]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1725511211.652714832] [spawner_ur5_controllers]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
[spawner-7] [WARN] [1725511221.673485801] [spawner_ur5_controllers]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1725511221.674899434] [spawner_ur5_controllers]: waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available...
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[ros2_control_node-6] [INFO] [1725511222.999829944] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725511223.000005662] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 9460]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 9450]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 9462]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 9452]
[INFO] [gzserver-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 9454]
[INFO] [gzclient-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 9456]

Here is my launch file:
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import PathJoinSubstitution
import os
import xacro
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


def generate_launch_description():
    share_dir = get_package_share_directory('ur5_assembly_description')

    # Path to the xacro file
    xacro_file = os.path.join(share_dir, 'urdf', 'ur5_assembly.xacro')
    robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)
    robot_urdf = robot_description_config.toxml()

    # Path to the controller YAML configuration
    controller_config = os.path.join(share_dir, 'config', 'controllers.yaml')

    # Robot State Publisher
    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[
            {'robot_description': robot_urdf}
        ]
    )

    # Joint State Publisher
    joint_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher'
    )

    # Gazebo server
    gazebo_server = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
            PathJoinSubstitution([
                FindPackageShare('gazebo_ros'),
                'launch',
                'gzserver.launch.py'
            ])
        ]),
        launch_arguments={
            'pause': 'true'
        }.items()
    )

    # Gazebo client
    gazebo_client = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
            PathJoinSubstitution([
                FindPackageShare('gazebo_ros'),
                'launch',
                'gzclient.launch.py'
            ])
        ])
    )

    # Spawn the robot in Gazebo
    urdf_spawn_node = Node(
        package='gazebo_ros',
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        arguments=[
            '-entity', 'ur5_assembly',
            '-topic', 'robot_description'
        ],
        output='screen'
    )

    # Controller Manager Node
    controller_manager_node = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='ros2_control_node',
        parameters=[controller_config],
        output='screen'
    )

    # Spawner node for Joint Group Position Controller
    joint_group_position_controller_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['ur5_controllers'],  # Ensure this matches your controller YAML
        output='screen'
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        gazebo_server,
        gazebo_client,
        urdf_spawn_node,
        controller_manager_node,
        joint_group_position_controller_spawner,
    ])

Here is my Controller.yaml file
ur5_controllers:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 1000  # Hz 

    joint_group_position_controller:
      type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster   


joint_group_position_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - base_link1_joint
      - link1_link2p1_joint
      - link2p3_link3_joint
      - link3_link4_joint
      - link4_link5_joint
      - link5_link6_joint
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      

Here is my xacro
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="ur5_assembly" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

<xacro:include filename="$(find ur5_assembly_description)/urdf/materials.xacro" />
<xacro:include filename="$(find ur5_assembly_description)/urdf/ur5_assembly.trans" />
<xacro:include filename="$(find ur5_assembly_description)/urdf/ur5_assembly.gazebo" />

<link name="world">
</link>

<link name="base_link">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.0033230512143046006 -0.0004232197888539764 0.037822190938846395" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.5345680035783248"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000677" iyy="0.000677" izz="0.001135" ixy="-1.9e-05" iyz="0.0" ixz="-0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/base_link.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/base_link.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="link2_p1_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="6.203040415705269e-06 0.06207005674361077 0.007860389181770538" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="1.5524700894200791"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.003628" iyy="0.003009" izz="0.003383" ixy="-1e-06" iyz="-0.000207" ixz="-0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.003691 -0.075244 -0.110286" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link2_p1_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.003691 -0.075244 -0.110286" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link2_p1_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="link2_p2_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-8.752471172565526e-05 2.4376620175181607e-07 0.1524996678439083" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="1.937681145922208"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.017402" iyy="0.017402" izz="0.001914" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="1e-06"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.003693 -0.142247 -0.176586" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link2_p2_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.003693 -0.142247 -0.176586" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link2_p2_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="link2_p3_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-7.763250047288905e-06 -0.004932943256389266 0.05843895228729162" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="1.5524700894200791"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.003628" iyy="0.003009" izz="0.003383" ixy="1e-06" iyz="0.000207" ixz="-0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.003704 -0.142247 -0.481586" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link2_p3_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.003704 -0.142247 -0.481586" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link2_p3_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="link3_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.17378102072172863 -0.04787490591742441 0.00100186606907815" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="2.846539405621545"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.003063" iyy="0.061797" izz="0.062318" ixy="0.003731" iyz="2.2e-05" ixz="-0.000342"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.003706 -0.075244 -0.547886" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link3_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.003706 -0.075244 -0.547886" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link3_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="link4_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="2.12490884528016e-05 0.04182917130330904 -0.003987177325129543" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.5732810659722621"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000753" iyy="0.000581" izz="0.000587" ixy="0.0" iyz="1.1e-05" ixz="0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.388538 -0.063244 -0.550142" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link4_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.388538 -0.063244 -0.550142" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link4_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="link5_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.003851364362202292 4.3924354040825175e-05 0.04240877360333983" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.5732811937839646"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000597" iyy="0.000754" izz="0.000572" ixy="1e-06" iyz="0.0" ixz="2e-05"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.388441 -0.116864 -0.591692" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link5_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.388441 -0.116864 -0.591692" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link5_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="link6_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.01818377138506838 -7.537991570427671e-05 0.0001621667781095404" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.1747134109193075"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000123" iyy="8.2e-05" izz="8.3e-05" ixy="-0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="-0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.429865 -0.116512 -0.645408" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link6_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.429865 -0.116512 -0.645408" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link6_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="link1_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-5.118812714607554e-06 0.016411047782836283 0.05864433019110279" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="1.667428920912541"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.004178" iyy="0.003273" izz="0.003817" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.000173" ixz="1e-06"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.003691 5.6e-05 -0.050586" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link1_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.003691 5.6e-05 -0.050586" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ur5_assembly_description)/meshes/link1_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<joint name="world_base_joint" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  <parent link="world"/>
  <child link="base_link"/>
</joint>

<joint name="link1_link2p1_joint" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.0 0.0753 0.0597" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="link1_1"/>
  <child link="link2_p1_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 -1.0 -0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="p1_p2_joint" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="-2e-06 0.067003 0.0663" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="link2_p1_1"/>
  <child link="link2_p2_1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="p2_p3_joint" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="-1.1e-05 0.0 0.305" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="link2_p2_1"/>
  <child link="link2_p3_1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="link2p3_link3_joint" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="-2e-06 -0.067003 0.0663" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="link2_p3_1"/>
  <child link="link3_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 -1.0 -0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="link3_link4_joint" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.392244 -0.012 0.002256" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="link3_1"/>
  <child link="link4_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 -0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="link4_link5_joint" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="-9.7e-05 0.05362 0.04155" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="link4_1"/>
  <child link="link5_1"/>
  <axis xyz="-0.00232 0.0 0.999997"/>
</joint>

<joint name="link5_link6_joint" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.041424 -0.000352 0.053716" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="link5_1"/>
  <child link="link6_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.999962 -0.008461 0.00232"/>
</joint>

<joint name="base_link1_joint" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="-0.003691 -5.6e-05 0.050586" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="link1_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 -0.0 1.0"/>
</joint>

</robot>

Here is my .trans file
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="ur5_assembly" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" >

<transmission name="link1_link2p1_joint_tran">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="link1_link2p1_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="link1_link2p1_joint_actr">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link2p3_link3_joint_tran">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="link2p3_link3_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="link2p3_link3_joint_actr">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link3_link4_joint_tran">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="link3_link4_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="link3_link4_joint_actr">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link4_link5_joint_tran">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="link4_link5_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="link4_link5_joint_actr">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="link5_link6_joint_tran">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="link5_link6_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="link5_link6_joint_actr">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name="base_link1_joint_tran">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="base_link1_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="base_link1_joint_actr">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
</transmission>

<ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
  <hardware>
    <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
  </hardware>
  <joint name="base_link1_joint">
    <command_interface name="position"/>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    <state_interface name="effort"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="link1_link2p1_joint">
    <command_interface name="position"/>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    <state_interface name="effort"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="link2p3_link3_joint">
    <command_interface name="position"/>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    <state_interface name="effort"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="link3_link4_joint">
    <command_interface name="position"/>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    <state_interface name="effort"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="link4_link5_joint">
    <command_interface name="position"/>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    <state_interface name="effort"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="link5_link6_joint">
    <command_interface name="position"/>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    <state_interface name="effort"/>
  </joint>  

</ros2_control>


</robot>

Gazebo file
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="ur5_assembly" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" >

<xacro:property name="silver" value="Gazebo/Silver" />
<xacro:property name="blue" value="Gazebo/Blue" />
<xacro:property name="black" value="Gazebo/Black" />


<gazebo>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
    <parameters>~/ros2_ws/src/ur5_assembly_description/config/controller.yaml</parameters>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="base_link">
  <material>${blue}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <self_collide>true</self_collide>
  <gravity>true</gravity>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link2_p1_1">
  <material>${blue}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <self_collide>true</self_collide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link2_p2_1">
  <material>${silver}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <self_collide>true</self_collide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link2_p3_1">
  <material>${blue}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <self_collide>true</self_collide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link3_1">
  <material>${silver}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <self_collide>true</self_collide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link4_1">
  <material>${blue}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <self_collide>true</self_collide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link5_1">
  <material>${silver}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <self_collide>true</self_collide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link6_1">
  <material>${black}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <self_collide>true</self_collide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link1_1">
  <material>${silver}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <self_collide>true</self_collide>
</gazebo>

</robot>


Why don't you use the official simulation files for the UR?
I see several issues:

there is no ros2_control section in your URDF
you don't need to launch ros2_control_node if you are using gazebo

please have a look at our demos or the gazebo_ros2_control_demos and adapt that for your robot.
